# Which countries are denying entry for people with mixed COVID-19 vaccines?

Tags: air-travel, covid-19

A few countries (Canada, Germany, Italy, UK, Thailand) encouraged their citizens to get mixed COVID-19 vaccines (eg. 1st dose Pfizer, 2nd dose Moderna) during the early stages of vaccination.

Now some countries are [announcing](https://www.cbc.ca/news/world/united-states-biden-travel-1.6182300) that they will only allow visitors who are fully vaccinated, where "fully vaccinated" requires both vaccine shots to be of the same type. In other words, people with mixed vaccines would be prohibited from entering the country.

Which countries are denying entry for people with **mixed** COVID-19 vaccines?

Comment: Do you really mean "denying entry" or just not considering them as vaccinated?

Comment: When I read your question, I wanted to ask if you can giv an example for such countries.

Answer (score 1):

### Trinidad & Tobago

A mix of Pfizer & Moderna does not count as fully vaccinated ([source](https://www.facebook.com/MinistryofHealthTT/photos/moh-media-release-new-who-approved-covid-19-vaccine-combination-the-ministry-of-/4635809886448783/)).

### No Longer Restricted

- France did not originally recognize mixed vaccines, but the [current policy](https://ca.ambafrance.org/COVID-19-Measures-for-foreign-nationals-wishing-to-travel-to-France) is to "accept the following vaccine combinations: AstraZeneca/Pfizer Cominarty - AstraZeneca/Moderna and Pfizer/Moderna"